# div centering in html for wordpress

Tags: css, html

```
<div id="logo" style="center"><img src="logo1.png"></img></div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
```

This doesn't work.
Whats the problem with the style of the div? i'm sure the syntax is wrong.

Comment: what is `style="center"`?? And Why you are closing two `div`?

Comment: I added a div for the sake of example and missed that i already had one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. "center" is not a style. You're probably looking for `text-align: center`.
2. Images are self-closing like the line-break. You don't use `</img>`.
3. You have a spare closing `</div>` at the end of the line. One of them needs removed, I'm not sure which spot you want it in.

```
<div id="logo" style="text-align: center"><img src="logo1.png"></div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Okay so what happened is that the stupid logo is hard coded in the styles to be aligned left. So when I removed div id, now the logo is too low. Is there a way to bring it up using the y coordinate?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot define style in div like that instead you can define the div property in css and call the class or id of the css.

Comment: Cannot define it like that? I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: the title was centering div not its content so I might not have understood what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  You have to set the width of a div as shown below in order for it to work. To specify that the text *inside* the div is centered, simply apply style="text-align: center"

```
<div id="logo" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 500px; border: 1px solid #ff0000">Your content here....</div>
```

Note: set 500px width to your desired width.  Also, remove border: directive.  I just added that so you could see the DIV was centered.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P26m3/)

Comment: Note that this centers the div *horizontally*.  For vertical centering, it's a bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to center a  element is probably to specify its width and put the side margin to auto:

If for example your logo1.png is 570px wide, you would do something like this in the css

```
#logo{
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:570px;
}
```